# Redondear valores c#

Tags: c#

Estoy intentando redondear los valores obtenidos desde mi web service pero no encuentro como formarlo. Alguien puede ayudarme.

```
else if (SistemaID == 223)
{
    string url = "https://normonapi.normon.com/EBR/AC2-18COMPLETADO";
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
    dynamic datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
         
    foreach(var i in datos)
    {
        this.txtProgreso.Text = Conversor.convertirString(Math.Round(i.Value_Double +"%"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en esta parte del código puedes ver que estás intentando hacer un `Round` de un string.

```
`Math.Round(i.Value_Double +"%")
```

Si lo que deseas es que el valor resultante sea un porcentaje, primero lo redondeas y luego le asignas el formato, o mejor, utiliza el método `ToString` que te permite asignar el formato a visualizar, en tu caso sería "P1" donde "P" significa porcentaje y "1" significa 1 posición decimal

```
this.txtProgreso.Text = i.Value_Double.ToString("P1");
```

Si no quieres ningún decimal le indicas `.ToString("P0");`

Si previamente quieres redondear la cifra puedes incluir el `round` antes de pasarlo a string.

```
this.txtProgreso.Text = Math.Round(i.Value_Double,2).ToString("P0");
```

El resultado, si el valor de origen es de 0.989543 sería de 99%.

**EDITO**

Debes controlar que el valor de `i.Value_Double` no sea `null`, para ello puedes asignar primero el valor a una variable. Si el valor es nulo, lo convierte en cero.

```
double? valor = i.Value_Double != null ? Math.Round(i.Value_Double, 2) : 0;
this.txtProgreso.Text = valor.ToString("P0");
```

Comment: Si algo así es, pero el valor no es correcto. No tiene en cuenta la "coma" de los valores. Por ejemplo: Valor sin redondear que cojo es 99,524534 %y con lo que he realizado me redondea a 9.524%. No toma en cuenta la "coma", debería ser 99%

Comment: Hola Roger, la ultima opción no me permite realizarlo, ya que me obliga a convertir string. Y no puedo aplicar las dos funciones a la vez. Como podría realizarlo?

Comment: Yo acabo de probar `this.txtProgreso.Text = Math.Round(i.Value_Double,2).ToString("P0"); y funciona perfectamente.`

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Math.Round(double, int)' has some invalid arguments.       Este es el error que tengo al realizarlo así

Comment: Tendrás que controlar que `i.Value_Double` no sea `null`, edito la respuesta

Comment: En realidad el valor nunca es nullo, aplique lo que me indicas y tengo error de sobrecarga=No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments.